# Jest 27: How to reset mock for jest.spyOn(window, "setTimeout")?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am updating a project from jest version 26 to jest version 27. As part of the update I had to switch from assertions on `setTimeout` to assertions on `jest.spyOn(window, "setTimeout")`.

I want to define spy globally and reset it before each test, something like:

```
const timeoutSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "setTimeout");
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
});
```

This code doesn't work as I expected. Assertions for `expect(timeoutSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(n)` fail due to mismatch of expected (n) and received (0) number of calls.

What is the correct way to reset a globally defined timeoutSpy before each test?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jest.restoreAllMocks()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrestoreallmocks).

> Restores all mocks back to their original value. Equivalent to calling `.mockRestore()` on every mocked function. Beware that `jest.restoreAllMocks()` only works when the mock was created with `jest.spyOn`; other mocks will require you to manually restore them.

Answer (score 0):

### READ / DONT COPY

I'm using:

- NodeJS v16.17.0
- NPM 8.19.1
- Jest ^25.1.0

For me the **only** solution worked was to use `MockXXXOnce` **and do not restoring it**, specially with timer, it seem reseting mocks such as this

```js
const spySetTimeout = jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout')
```

and doing something like:

```js
spySetTimeout.mockReset() // mockRestore() ...
```

corrupt the timers, or anyhow the original implementation will no longer work

for this I did

```
spySetTimeout.mockReturnValueOnce(1000)
```

only on `it(x, async ()=>{})` tests that I need.

storing function reference will not work either, as at least the jest `spyOn` mocking will sit on the actual function

Answer (score -1):

Using `jest.resetAllMocks();` in the `beforeEach` should be sufficient. The code below can be used to prove it:

```
function callTimeout() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('hello');
  })
}

const timeoutSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'setTimeout');

describe("test timeout", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it("test 1", () => {
    callTimeout();
    callTimeout();
    expect(timeoutSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  })

  it("test 2", () => {
    callTimeout();
    callTimeout();
    expect(timeoutSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  })
});
```

I had to test `testEnvironment` property in `jest.config.js` file to `jsdom` for `window` variable to work. However you can replace `window` to `global` for it to work with the default as `node`.